# Use of "should have" in conditional sentences

Tags: modal-verbs, conditionals, conditional-perfect

In *Return of the Soldier* (1918) I came across what appears to be a conditional sentence:

> I never **should have** got this telegram if me and my husband hadn't been down there last September and told the folks [...] who I was.

Why have I never seen conditional sentences formed this way before, and why is it not covered in the [relevant Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence) either?  What is the grammar behind it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The NOAD reports the following notes about *would* and *should*:

> The traditional rule is that *should* is used with first person pronouns (*I* and *we*), as in "I said I should be late," and *would* is used with second and third persons (*you*, *he*, *she*, *it*, *they*), as in "you didn't say you would be late." In practice, however, *would* is normally used instead of *should* in reported speech and conditional clauses: "I said I would be late"; "if we had known, we would have invited her."

The sentence uses what the NOAD calls the traditional rule, where *would* is normally used nowadays.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Although I should not have asked if I had looked it up in a dictionary first ;-)

Answer (score 3):

*Should* can indeed be used to express the conditional mood, although the *New Oxford American Dictionary* marks it as “formal”:

> **should**
> 3. *formal*  expressing the conditional mood
>
> - (in the first person) indicating the consequence of an imagined event: *if I were to obey my first impulse, I should spend my days writing letters*.
> - referring to a possible event or situation: *if you should change your mind, I'll be at the hotel*; *should anyone arrive late, admission is likely to be refused*.

Comment: +1. The first case seems to cover the usage in the OP's question. The second, however, looks like a different syntax to me (*should* is in the conditional clause, not in the main one).